# How can I fix a "can't find referenced class com.google.protobuf"?

Tags: java, mysql, proguard

I've been trying to use Proguard and have hit a wall. I run my program fine until it attempts an SQL connection (that works without proguard) at which point it doesn't connect with the (error on end for readability).

I've tried to run without warnings and I will get over 20000 unresolved references or classing relating to com.google.protobuf. I've attempted -keeping  SQL, java, protobuf, and including MySQL jar as a -libraryjar:

> Warning: com.mysql.cj.x.protobuf.MysqlxSql$StmtExecuteOrBuilder: can't find referenced class com.google.protobuf.ByteString

Here is my current proguard config without the default stuff at the end:

```
-injars 'C:\Users\Bobby\Desktop\mainApp\mainApp.jar'
-outjars 'C:\Users\Bobby\Desktop\mainApp\mainAppOut.jar'
-libraryjars 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_172\lib\rt.jar'
-libraryjars 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_172\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar'

-classobfuscationdictionary OBF.txt

-dontoptimize
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,LocalVariable*Table,*Annotation*,Synthetic,EnclosingMethod
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-adaptclassstrings mainApp.mainUI
-adaptresourcefilenames **.properties,**.fxml,**.css
-adaptresourcefilecontents **.properties,META-INF/MANIFEST.MF,**.fxml
-dontnote
-dontwarn

##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for JavaFx ----------
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @javafx.fxml.FXML *;
}

-keep,allowobfuscation class mainApp.**

-keep class com.mainApp {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
##---------------End: proguard configuration for JavaFX----------
# Keep - Applications. Keep all application classes, along with their 'main' methods.
-keepclasseswithmembers public class * {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}

# Also keep - Database drivers. Keep all implementations of java.sql.Driver.
-keep class * extends java.sql.Driver
-keep class com.google.protobuf.** { *; }
```

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mysql.cj.b.D cannot be cast to com.mysql.cj.b.j
        at com.mysql.cj.g.K.a(SourceFile:162)
        at com.mysql.cj.g.K.a(SourceFile:196)
        at com.mysql.cj.a.F.a(SourceFile:257)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(SourceFile:196)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at mainApp.E.a(SourceFile:159)
        at mainApp.E.c(SourceFile:189)
        at mainApp.E.a(SourceFile:95)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.process(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.access$1600(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleKeyEvent$1(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: is mainApp.jar a fat jar ?